# Can I add code to the default constructor and another dilemma

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am dynamically assigning a form (think of it as a "pseudo tab page") to a tabcontrol.

I was doing it this way:

// Main form, which has the TabControl at design-time:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    int TabControlWidth = tabPageBasicInfo.Size.Width;
    int TabControlHeight = tabPageBasicInfo.Size.Height;

    if (e.Node.Name == "NodeWhatever")
    {
        BasicInfoPseudoTab bipt = new BasicInfoPseudoTab(TabControlWidth, TabControlHeight);
        tabPageBasicInfo.Controls.Add(bipt);
        bipt.Show();
    }
    // else NodeThis, NodeThat
}
```

// Constructor on the form that is the "pseudo tab page":

```
// overloaded constructor, passing in the dimensions of the tab page
public BasicInfoPseudoTab(int ATabPageWidth, int ATabPageHeight) 
{
    this.TopLevel = false;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.Width = ATabPageWidth;
    this.Height = ATabPageHeight;
    this.Visible = true;
}
```

...but then I experimented with setting the Dock property:

```
public BasicInfoPseudoTab(int ATabPageWidth, int ATabPageHeight) 
{
    this.TopLevel = false;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    //this.Width = ATabPageWidth;
    //this.Height = ATabPageHeight;
    this.Visible = true;
    this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;         
}
```

...and it works great, so I thought I'd just use the "in the box" constructor by stripping out the two args. However, that's not allowed, as get, "Type 'UserControlsOnTabPagePOCApp.BasicInfoPseudoTab' already defines a member called 'BasicInfoPseudoTab' with the same parameter types"

The Load() event is too late (when I was setting the TopLevel property there, it gave me an err msg until I moved it to the constructor).

What do I need to do to override (rather than overload) the constructor, or what other event should I use (does anything come before the Load() event?)

ALSO (I didn't want to put the same code in two different questions): the form itself displays fine on the TabControl, but the controls I've added to the form/pseudo Tag page at design-time do not display at run-time - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a matter of overriding a constructor (constructors aren't polymorphic like that anyway) - it's a matter of the constructor already existing. I'd *expect* it to be present already in your code - something like this:

```
public BasicInfoPseudoTab()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

You can *edit* that constructor, rather than declaring another parameterless one. Note that your other constructor should either chain to that one or call `InitializeComponent()` itself, so that all the designer code can do its stuff.

Comment: It was hiding in plain sight.